# Python Tkinter count-down GUI crashing when i start the Count-Down with a button. (app not answering)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, timer, crash

I am making a count-down GUI with Tkinter in Python 3.10 and I'm making a slider that sets the minutes, 2 labels that display the minutes and seconds and a button to start the timer.

The problem is that it crashes when I click the start timer button, The strange thing is that it doesn't give me any error messages it just doesn't respond/crashes the GUI.

I'm using functions with long loops and I think the problem is with the loops.

Both the slider and Button calls functions

I'm a beginner so I know that the code isn't so good but I'm trying my best. Please Help Me :)

Python Code:

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x400")
root.title("Countdown Timer")

time = 0
time_2 = 0

running = False
def clear_field():
    clock_text_min.delete(1.0, "end")
    clock_text_sec.delete(1.0, "end")
    min_slider.set(30)


def before_start_timer(time):
    global time_2
    time_2 = time
    time = int(time)
    time_3 = str(time)
    counter = 0
    while (not running) and (counter < 10):
        clock_text_min.config(text=time_3)
        counter += 1

def start_timer(time):
    global running
    running = True
    time = int(time)
    while time >= 0:
        clock_text_min.config(text=time)
        sec_time = 60
        for _ in range(60):
            clock_text_sec.config(text=sec_time)
            sleep(1)
            sec_time -= 1
        time -= 1

clock_text_min = Label(root, text="0", font=("Arial", 25))
clock_text_min.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

clock_text_sec = Label(root, text="0", font=("Arial", 25))
clock_text_sec.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

min_slider = Scale(root, from_=1, to=60, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=before_start_timer)
min_slider.set(30)
min_slider.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

start_button = Button(root, text="Start Countdown", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: start_timer(time_2))
start_button.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Its a very difficult problem so i haven't tried anything yet because i dont understand the problem, but as i said i think the problem is in the loops.

I was expecting it to start coundting down from the set number of minutes and when its finished just stop at 0 on both min and sec but it just crashed when i clicked start countdown.

Please help me, it would be really helpfull because this is my second GUI i have ever made without any help :)

code is fixed/question ended

Hi everyone, thanks for all the help, my code is now working by using the after function and the root.update_idletasks() function. thanks

Comment: You should avoid using `sleep` in conjunction with tkinter, as it will cause your app to hang whenever it's "sleeping". Tkinter has a built-in method called `after` that's very useful for triggering callbacks after a set number of milliseconds.

Comment: I will also add to @JRiggles statement that the WHILE loop will also be causing problems. You can managed callback with a refactored function and `after()` to effectively do the same thing without freezing your application.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try to fix the code with all of your suggestions.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all the help, my code is now working by using the after function and the root.update_idletasks() function. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JRiggles mentioned sleep and tkinter do not go well. This is because `sleep()` blocks the main loop of tkinter.

The most common way to solve this issue is to use `after()` to manage these kind of loops.

Here is a paired down version of your code that uses a combination of `after()` and a refactored function.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")
root.title("Countdown Timer")


def start_timer(time):
    if time >= 0:
        clock_text_sec.config(text=time)
        time -= 1
        # you can supply a variable after the function call with after.
        root.after(1000, start_timer, time)
        # you can also use a lambda to do the same thing
        # root.after(1000, lambda: start_timer(time))


clock_text_sec = tk.Label(root, text="0", font=("Arial", 25))
clock_text_sec.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
tk.Button(root, text="Start Countdown", font=("Arial", 15), command=lambda: start_timer(60)).pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try to fix the code with all of your suggestions.

Comment: @axelrothing if my answer has solved your problem please select the check mark next to the answer to indicate your problem has been resolved.

Comment: Hi, Im gonna do that when i am able to make the code work, but i find it hard to follow your code so if you could copy my code, fix it and then post it as an answer with comments of what you have done, that would be amazing. I understand that this is difficult but i am a beginner coder so please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @axelrothing I can do that but I would like to know what exactly you are confused on.
Because what I have provided is one of the easier solution so I would need to know what about it is confusing.

Comment: I find it confusing to use the code you have given above with the min and sec because I want my GUI to have minutes and then it counts down from 60 sec every time the sec has reached 0, also it needs to subtract the minute count and config the min text. i was planning to make it so that when it has reached 0 it makes the text fg red and displays a notification with plyer that the timer has ended. it would be awesome if you could help. Thanks

Comment: the first label is the min and the second label is the sec

Comment: @axelrothing That is not the question you have asked in you post. Your issue was the crashing.
I provided the logic you need to stop the crashing. If you now need help with creating a proper clock you need to ask a new question on a new post.

Comment: no, that is the question i was asking if you could just make my code not crash without just giving me logic.

Comment: @axelrothing ***"The problem is that it crashes when I click the start timer button, The strange thing is that it doesn't give me any error messages it just doesn't respond/crashes the GUI."*** I have provided the logic to prevent this from happening. You are now asking more. As in asking how to build a clock using 2 separate labels. That is a different problem than stated in your question. That said if I have time today I might look at it again. You should try to use what I have provided you and see if you can make it work. Its not that hard to implement here.

Comment: Ok, Im gonna try to make it work

Comment: For everyone else reading this question, I’m still looking for more answers. Thanks

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all the help, my code is now working by using the after function and the root.update_idletasks() function. thanks

Comment: @axelrothing root.update_idletasks() should not be needed if you set up the function correctly.

Comment: I know, but it is the easy versjon so Im happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike mentioned you can't use sleep combined with Tkinter as it will freeze the main thread. The best option is to use the after() function tkinter has or if you want you can play around with the threading module so you don't block the main thread.